# ocaml vector space

Tags: vector, geometry, ocaml, space

I have a R3 space and I'm trying to figure some math "problems" with OCAML functions.

Define function "move", which moves plane based on the plane_name (ex. plane1) and vector (x, y, z):

example:

```
plane1 = [(1,2,-3); (10,5,2); (-2,3,7)]
move plane1 (1,2,-3);;
- : (int * int * int) list = [(2, 4, -6); (11, 7, -1); (-1, 5, 4)]
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you written any code that attempts to solve the problems? What does it look like, and what seems to be wrong with it?

Comment: i wasnt able to solve problems 3 and 4. I tried some random codes, but no luck. I'm sure these are basic problems but i just started to learn ocaml.

Comment: Sure, but it doesn't help if we just give you the answer (or at least this is what I think). Are you supposed to use functions from the `List` module, or are you supposed to *not* use functions from the `List` module (which is common at the beginning)?

Comment: I kind of know what i have to do, but I don't know how to put it in code. 
Prob 3)

We have a plane --> [(a,b,c); (a',b',c'); (a'',b'',c'')]. And if we want to move it with the vector we chose (x,y,z) --> then i have to create a function that will create a new list with:

    [(a+x, b+y, c+z); (a'+x, b'+y, c'+z); (a''+x, b''+y, c''+z)]. 
How to do this i have no idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll restrict my answer to problem 3.

I don't know where you're at with OCaml and what limitations have been imposed on your answer. (Forgive me, but I'm assuming this is a homework problem.) Let's assume the point of the exercise is to begin to think recursively. So then you want to write a function like this:

```
let move plane (x, y, z) = (( code goes here ))
```

For thinking recursively, the basic insight is that a plane is a list of points and you want to do the same thing to all the points. So a lower-level view of the function would be like this:

```
let rec move point_list (x, y, z) = (( code goes here ))
```

Now, a list is either empty, or it isn't. You just need to figure out what to do in each case. Furthermore, when the list is not empty you can use your own function recursively as long as you call it with a smaller list.

If, in fact, the point of this exercise is *not* to learn recursive thinking, then the answer would be completely different. In particular, there's a function in the `List` module that would make it pretty easy to solve the problem.

**Update**

Apparently you want to solve the problem non-recursively. To show how this would work, here is a function that takes two points and adds 1 to the x, y, and z coordinates of both points:

```
let add1 [(x1, y1, z1); (x2, y2, z2)] =
    [(x1 + 1, y1 + 1, z1 + 1); (x2 + 1, y2 + 1, z2 + 1)]
```

This will cause a compiler warning because it fails for many possible inputs. In particular, it fails whenever the list has some number of points other than 2. To eliminate the warning, we need to decide what we want to return for those cases. Let's say we always return the list unchanged in those cases. Then we get the following:

```
let add1 = function
    | [(x1, y1, z1); (x2, y2, z2)] ->
        [(x1 + 1, y1 + 1, z1 + 1); (x2 + 1, y2 + 1, z2 + 1)]
    | pts -> pts
```

I guess you know what you want, but this is not particularly idiomatic OCaml.

Another way to solve the problems non-recursively (without `rec`) would be to use functions from the `List` module. That would be much more idiomatic, and in fact is probably what I would do in a real-world situation.

Comment: You can solve the problem non-recursively for a fixed size list. I have some trouble believing this is a good solution. Assuming this is homework, it doesn't teach what I would (personally) be trying to teach my students. But I'll add some code you can look at.

Comment: This is precisely the compiler warning I was talking about.

Comment: imho the real problem is the plane representation as a list of point: a record would be much more adapted. But since this is homework, there's certainly a hidden goal.

Comment: True. But you could imagine the code would be expanded to handle hyperplanes in an arbitrary number of dimensions....

Comment: ...in which case you would need to loop over the list, and thus enable the use of recursion, which was not accepted by OP. It's one or the other indeed.